# How to assign Custom select box option value in custom form?

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, option, select

Here i working custom form with custom select box in magento.I need to assign Custom select box with option value attributes and option values .

Here i working custom form sample code:

```
$fabrics    = Mage::getModel('magentostudy_fabrics/fabrics')->getCollection(); 
        $fabricval[] = "Please Select";
        $fabricvals[] = "0";
        // $collection->addAttributeToSelect('news_id'); //retrieve only product name (optimising SQL)
        foreach ($fabrics as $fabric) //loop for getting products
        {
            $fabricval[] = $fabric->getTitle(); 
            $fabricvals[] = $fabric->getNews_id(); 
        }
 $fieldset->addField('fabricslist', 'select', array(
            'name'     => 'fabricslist',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('bulk_uploader')->__('Select Fabrics List'),
            'title'    => Mage::helper('bulk_uploader')->__('Select Fabrics List'),
            'required' => true,
            'onclick' => "",
            'onchange' => "",
            'value'  => $fabricvals,
            'values'    =>$fabricval,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
            'readonly' => false,
            'after_element_html' => '<small>choose Category list</small>',
            'tabindex' => 1   
        ));
```

Here  `'value'  => $fabricval` got wrong values.For example i have News_ID 1,3,5 respectively.But i results only 1,2,3 respectively.How to assign `value` attributes in select box
for example I need select box sample function

```
<select>
<option value='1'>sample1</option>
<option value='3'>sample2</option>
<option value='5'>sample3</option>
</select>
```

How to assign select box option value attributes in magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HereBy, Finally i found solution based on option value assignment with auto-increment value.

Simple adjustment in above code it return proper results

```
  $fabrics    = Mage::getModel('magentostudy_fabrics/fabrics')->getCollection(); 
  $fabricval[] = "Please Select";
  $fabricvals[] = "0";
  foreach ($fabrics as $fabric) {
     $id =$fabric->getNews_id();
     $fabricval[$id] = $fabric->getTitle(); 
  }
```

Here i made some change in my code, I get auto-increment id`($id =$fabric->getNews_id();$fabricval[$id] = $fabric->getTitle();)` and assign into array key value and place into custom form like this

```
$fieldset->addField('fabricslist', 'select', array(
            'name'     => 'fabricslist',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('bulk_uploader')->__('Select Fabrics List'),
            'title'    => Mage::helper('bulk_uploader')->__('Select Fabrics List'),
            'required' => true,
            'onclick' => "",
            'onchange' => "",
            'values'    =>$fabricval,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
            'readonly' => false,
            'after_element_html' => '<small>choose Category list</small>',
            'tabindex' => 1   
        ));
```

This results properly what i need

```
<select>
<option value='1'>sample1</option>
<option value='3'>sample2</option>
<option value='5'>sample3</option>
</select>
```